# Why address of local array variable changes in each invocation (ASLR diabled)?

Tags: c, variables, stack-overflow, memory-address, buffer-overflow

I was doing a buffer-overflow test. In function foo(), since buffer[256] is an array, I was expecting it to be present in stack at the same address (irrespective of how many bytes are strcpy to it). But, the address of buffer seems to be changed based on how much data is copied to it. I could not understand why it is happening. Can somebody please explain this? I thought disabling ASLR should be sufficient.

```
└─$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char *input);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        foo(argv[1]);
}

void foo(char *input)
{
        char buffer[256];
        printf ("%p\n", &buffer[0]);
        strcpy(buffer, input);
}

└─$ gcc -g -no-pie -fno-stack-protector a.c -o a -z execstack -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0

└─$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
0

└─$ ./a AA
0x7fffffffde50

└─$ ./a AAAAAAAA
0x7fffffffde40                          <<-- why it is changed now??

└─$ ./a AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
0x7fffffffde30                          <<-- why it is changed again??
```

Comment: well, the command line arguments must be stored somewhere too. Either in the stack itself or the buffer needed changes the start of the stack

Comment: What is address of `argv[1]`?

Answer (score 2):

`main` is not the first function called in a program, it's usually a function called `__start`, which does a few things, including initializing the C runtime, and in this implementation, probably retrieving the `main` arguments and copying them onto the stack before passing them. To save space, these particular buffers are probably allocated with `alloca` or similar. You could check the address of `input` to see if it is on the stack.

EDIT: Actually, in the case of linux/ELF format, it seems the arguments are already on the stack when `__start` is executed. The arguments are setup there by the sytem ELF loader, and `__start` just pass them to `main` (see a nice picture there https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/). But in any case, it is up to the system how it is done. Some platforms could that differently.